# In redis cluster how to get the data of whole cluster which is set by command HMSET by node redis client?

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

Is it possible by HSCAN command, Only providing the host and port of single node, which automatically detect the cluster node and gives all data?

currently made a temporary fix by iterating through all the node.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How exactly to do it is depends on client you are using.

Generally redis use XModem CRC 16 algorithm to determine where is the key stored, check this source code: https://github.com/h0x91b/fast-redis-cluster/blob/remake/index.js#L92:L175

To know where is the key actually stored you should calculate xmodem crc16 of the key name, then take module of 16384. The result is the `bucket number`, now you can use `CLUSTER NODES` command to determine which server serve this bucket..

For example, our key name is `123456789`

crc16 of `123456789` is 12739

12739 % 16384 = 12739, so our bucket is `12739`

Then run `CLUSTER NODES` command, not matter on which master\slave server.

You will see something like this:

```
2339fe27bd311835712965a764839b4acaf41d5c 127.0.0.1:7012@17012 slave b43c92c05670537a60bcbf5430fef5e66ddebbcf 0 1493302253929 4 connected
f3007f3c2bc3a2826a3ed8e54a5e651e7457161a 127.0.0.1:7001@17001 myself,master - 0 0 0 connected 0-8191
1a054a84924109d277133bc1c14b0266f21b9f29 127.0.0.1:7003@17003 master - 0 1493302250907 3 connected 16383
577877f65e2c57a60849f242a2e740e822642431 127.0.0.1:7011@17011 slave f3007f3c2bc3a2826a3ed8e54a5e651e7457161a 0 1493302254932 1 connected
b43c92c05670537a60bcbf5430fef5e66ddebbcf 127.0.0.1:7002@17002 master - 0 1493302249900 1 connected 8192-16382
47bf2c2f5e2e6acf10dff8568f8212a014335a5c 127.0.0.1:7013@17013 slave 1a054a84924109d277133bc1c14b0266f21b9f29 0 1493302252924 3 connected
```

Each line is a server. `2339fe27bd311835712965a764839b4acaf41d5c` is id of the server, then ip address and port, flags and settings.

We need to find the line which contain flag `master` and on the end of this line you will see what buckets this server are hosting.

In my case needed line is:

`b43c92c05670537a60bcbf5430fef5e66ddebbcf 127.0.0.1:7002@17002 master - 0 1493302249900 1 connected 8192-16382`

`8192-16382` <<< this server serve buckets 8192,8193,8194...16382 (inclusively) so our key located on server `127.0.0.1:7002`

There are only two syntaxes for buckets.

1. 1-125 - from 1 to 125
2. 1,3,5 - bucket 1 and 3 and 5
3. 1-10,15,18,20-100 - just mix of two above

One more thing, redis supports Hashtags in cluster mode, if the key looks like `hello{world}` crc16 we do only on 'hello' without '{world}' `crc16('hello')` this can help you to store the keys on same instance..

Comment: I got your point @h0x91B. In redis cluster if we set the data from HMSET, I am able to retrieve it through the HSCAN command

Answer (score 0):

Combination of node-redis and node-redis-streamify gives me the result as I expected...

```
var redis = require("redis");
require('node-redis-streamify')(redis);
// Host and port of single node
var client = redis.createClient({host:xyz, port:xyz});
var pattern = '*', count = 1000, hscan = client.streamified('HSCAN');
hscan(key, pattern, count)
    .on('data', function (data) {
        console.log('hscan data ***', data);
     })
    .on('error', function (error) {
        console.log('hscan error ***', error);
     })
    .on('end', function () {
        console.log('hscan end ***');
     });
```